# Saving javascript code to php variable doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript that works fine

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.delete').click(function()  
        {
            alert('passed');
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I saved all those script to a PHP variable

```
$phpVariable =  "<script>
    \$(document).ready(function(){
       \$('.delete').click(function()  
        {
            alert('passed');
        });
    });
</script>";
```

and echoed the variable (with or without backslash on dollar '$' sign inside javascript)

```
echo "$phpVariable";
```

The problem exists. Javascript doesn't work anymore.
Can we save javascript code to php variable without encountering mulfunction?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a horrible description of any problem. Instead, describe exactly what the problem is - in this case, what is the output and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo "$phpVariable"`?

Comment: You dont need to add backslashes in above code and what you are trying is possible, You need tomention errors you enconter in tool like firebug , so someone can help actually

Comment: @Ic the code I given above is simple to follow. It will  alert 'passed' when satisfied. So the word "doesn't work" is no need to elaborate. When it doesn't work, the alert 'passed' is not showing even if the event is fired.

Comment: @IvorySantos So you're telling me you've looked at the source of the resulting page and it looks exactly the same; that the *only* difference between when hardcoded and when using a variable is that the alert never shows?

Comment: @lc. exactly. But I already found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$phpVariable =  '<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(\'.delete\').click(function()  
    {
        alert(\'passed\');
    });
});
</script>';


echo $phpVariable;
```

Basically change all " into ' and then escape any ' within the code.

Comment: How does that change anything?

Comment: using " instead of ' evaluates all dollar signs within the code as variables if they arent escaped. Escaping apostrophe instead of dollar signs is the more sensible approach. I believe escaping the dollar sign is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can not view Javascript in front end..

View source code of page, It already printed...

try this ...

```
echo htmlspecialchars($phpVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074058/javascript-doesnt-work-with-php-echo/19074253#19074253)

adding only

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

above the place where you are going to echo the $phpVariableScript

Sorry for some kind of duplicate question.
I found the right answer after I posted the question.
Should I delete this or link to the right answer?